# Read a binary array with mixed types

Tags: octave

I am writing a function similar to [this](https://github.com/treegraph/source/blob/v.01-alpha/treegraph/third_party/ply_io.py) to read in binary formatted .ply files.

The linked function reads the header and the skips to the binary array, reading that in with numpy and I would like to do the same in Octave.

My code for reading the header is

```
fid = fopen('/path/to/file.ply');
tline = fgetl(fid); % read first line
len = 0;
prop = {};
dtype = {};
fmt = 'binary';

while ~strcmp(tline, "end_header")

    len = len + length(tline) + 1; % increase header length, +1 includes EOL
    tline = strsplit(tline); % split string
    if strcmp('format', tline{1}) && strcmp('ascii', tline{2}) % test whether file is ascii
        fmt = 'ascii';
    end
    if strcmp('element', tline{1}) && strcmp('vertex', tline{2}) % number of points
        N = tline{3};
    end
    if strcmp('property', tline{1}) % identify fields
        dtype = [dtype, tline{2}];
        prop = [prop, tline{3}];
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
len = len + length(tline) + 1; % add 'end_header' to len
```

So I have arrays of data types

```
dtype =
{
  [1,1] = float
  [1,2] = float
  [1,3] = float
  [1,4] = int
  [1,5] = int
  [1,6] = int
  [1,7] = float
  [1,8] = float
  [1,9] = float
}
```

and I know the shape of the array.

```
N = 61415
```

Is there a function that replicates numpy's `fromfile` and can I `seek` to the right location in my file (I know where the binary data starts in the file as I have `len`)

Following @tasos-papastylianou answer I tried

```
fseek(fid, len);
fread(fid, 3, 'float')
```

Which returns the correct 3 values, but the next value is an integer and therefore gives the incorrect answer.

```
fread(fid, 4, 'float')

arr =

  -1.4298e+00
  -5.3943e+00
   1.6623e+01
   1.5274e-43 <<<< should be 109
```

#### My solution

```
function pts = read_ply(fn)

    fid = fopen(fn);
    tline = fgetl(fid); % read first line

    len = 0;
    prop = {};
    % dtype_map = {'float': 'f4', 'uchar': 'B', 'int':'i'}
    dtype = {};
    fmt = 'binary';

    while ~strcmp(tline, "end_header")

        len = len + length(tline) + 1; % increase header length, +1 includes EOL

        tline = strsplit(tline); % split string
        if strcmp('format', tline{1}) && strcmp('ascii', tline{2}) % test whether file is ascii
            fmt = 'ascii';
        elseif strcmp('element', tline{1}) && strcmp('vertex', tline{2}) % number of points
            N = str2num(tline{3});
        elseif strcmp('property', tline{1}) % identify fields
            dtype = [dtype, tline{2}];
            prop = [prop, tline{3}];
        endif
        tline = fgetl(fid);
    endwhile

    len = len + length(tline) + 1; % add 'end_header
    
% total file length minus header
fseek(fid, 0, 1);
file_length = ftell(fid) - len;

types = struct('float', 4, 'int', 4, 'float64', 8);
pts = struct();
seek_plus = 0;

for i = 1:length(prop)
    fseek(fid, len + seek_plus);
    dt = types.(dtype{i}); % dtype for field
    pts.(prop{i}) = fread(fid, N, dtype{i}, int32(file_length / N) - dt);
    seek_plus = seek_plus + dt;
endfor
```

This does not answer my original question as it involves a loop, but it seems fairly efficient. Arrays can be constructed as so.

```
xyz = [pts.x, pts.y, pts.z];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question confuses me a bit towards the end, since the most direct equivalent to numpy's saving an array in a numpy-specific binary format is octave's `save` which saves an array to an octave-specific binary format.

Having said that, this doesn't sound like what you want so I'm assuming the `fromfile` reference is a red herring.

In general if you have a binary file you want to open, read, or seek (i.e. place the cursor at a particular position), you can use the `fopen`, `fread`, and `fseek` commands. Also useful, `ftell`, `frewind`, etc.

These are all fairly simple commands. Just have a look at their documentation in the terminal (e.g. `help fseek` ).

Comment: Thanks @tasos. np.fromfile construct an array from data in a text or binary file (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). I tried fseek(fid, len); arr = fread(fid) but how do I specify data types as in my array dtype?

Comment: have a look at the documentation of `fread` (i.e. do `help fread` in your terminal -- if you want a 'paged' view, type `more on` and navigate with the arrow keys, exit with `q`). You will see in the documentation that you can specify a 3rd argument (called PRECISION) which defines your datatype, i.e. how the read bytes should be interpreted. E.g. if your data was saved as a 64-bity floating point number, you can do `fread( fid, len, 'float64' )`.